# xslt 1.0 xml merging between 2 nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

could you please help me on this one? 
I've been trying to merge 2 xml node based on key in xslt 1.0, but I'm not getting anywhere unfortunately.

This is the XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csv>
   <line>
      <field>DE</field>
      <field/>
      <field>DE:STN</field>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
   </line>
   <line>
      <field>DE</field>
      <field>DE:MWST</field>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
   </line>
   <line>
      <field>SI</field>
      <field/>
      <field>SI:MSPRS</field>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
   </line>

   <line>
      <field>BE</field>
      <field>BE:BTW</field>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
   </line>
</csv>
```

And I should have the following XML output in merging the lines which have the same line/field[1] as key, but very important preserving the order of values for line/field[i]  between the lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csv>
   <line>
      <field>DE</field>
      <field>DE:MWST</field>
      <field>DE:STN</field>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
   </line>
   <line>
      <field>SI</field>
      <field/>
      <field>SI:MSPRS</field>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
   </line>

   <line>
      <field>BE</field>
      <field>BE:BTW</field>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
      <field/>
   </line>
</csv>
```

If you could please give me a hint on how to solve this it would be great :)!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: this is a *grouping* problem. Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html  and come back if you run into a **specific** problem with the implementation.

Comment: Also, it is not clear from your example what should happen when the merged lines have conflicting values in the same field.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did tried to use Muenchian grouping, but all I've succeeded was to have the doubled lines in a single big line with all the children node fields, but the scope was to have the same number of children fields in the output and have the field[2] / field[3] values brought together in a single line. There can only be field[2] or field[3] present on entries with the same field[1] between the lines. Unfortunately I've lost all my attempts and I cannot provide a valid xsl now. I'll come back with one as soon as I'll be redoing it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following stylesheet. It uses the Muenchian method to group the `line`s by the value of the first `field`, then populates each `field` with the value of the first `field` of the group in the same position that has a string value.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="line" match="line" use="field[1]" />

<xsl:template match="/csv">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="line[count(. | key('line', field[1])[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('line', field[1])" />
                <xsl:for-each select="field">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <xsl:copy>  
                        <xsl:value-of select="$current-group/field[$i][string()]"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you very much ! It did exactly what I was aiming for! With some minor tweaks I was able to have my scope completed!